# Inverse of $A \otimes I_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Suppose $A \in GL(n)$ and $I_3$ is the identity in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is it true that

$$
\left( A \otimes I_3\right)^{-1} = A^{-1} \otimes I_3?
$$
(Here $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product).

**My Attempt** : I believe it is because defining the homomorphism $f : GL(n) \to \text{range}(f)$ as $f(A) = A \otimes I_3$ it is easy to verify that

$$
f(AB) = f(A)f(B)
$$

and that $f$ is also a bijection. Denoting with $I_n$ the identity in $GL(n)$ and $I_{3n}$ the identity in $\text{range}(f)$ we have

$$
I_{3n} = f(I_n) = f(AA^{-1}) = f(A)f(A^{-1}) = (A\otimes I_3) (A^{-1} \otimes I_3)
$$

Since the inverse is unique and $f$ is a bijection it must be

$$
(A^{-1} \otimes I_3) = (A \otimes I_3)^{-1}
$$

Is it correct?

Comment: It looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $A, B \in M(n, \mathbb{R})$, the matrix $A \otimes B$ is invertible if and only if both $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are invertible and its inverse is $A^{-1} \otimes B^{-1}$. In other words, the following equality holds:
$$(A \otimes B)^{-1} = A^{-1} \otimes B^{-1}$$

The proof is immediate from the definition of the Kronecker product. I write here the case $n = 2$, but the general case can be proved in a similar fashion.

For (invertible) $A = \begin{pmatrix}a_1 & a_2\\ a_3 & a_4\end{pmatrix}$, $B = \begin{pmatrix}b_1 & b_2\\ b_3 & b_4\end{pmatrix}$, and writting $A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} c_1 & c_2 \\ c_3 & c_4 \end{pmatrix}$ we have
$$(A \otimes B)(A^{-1} \otimes B^{-1}) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 B & a_2 B\\
a_3 B & a_4 B
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1 B^{-1} & c_2 B^{-1}\\
c_3 B^{-1} & c_4 B^{-1}
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
(a_1c_1 + a_2c_3)I_2 & (a_1c_2 + a_2c_4) I_2\\
(a_3c_1 + a_4c_3) I_2 & (a_3c_2 + a_4c_4)I_2
\end{pmatrix}\\
= \begin{pmatrix}
I_2 & 0\\
0 & I_2
\end{pmatrix} = I_4
$$
where the third equality follows just from the fact $AA^{-1} = I_2$. Then, we just proved that $(A \otimes B)^{-1} = A^{-1} \otimes B^{-1}$.

The proof for general $n$ follows exactly the same argument, but we have to write more parameters. Try to repeat it for matrices of size $n$ and you will obtain the result.

Comment: The statement you gave is redundant "For any $A,B \in GL(n)$ the matrix $A \oplus B$ is invertible iff $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ are invertible" obviously if $A,B \in GL(n)$ then $A,B,A^{-1},B^{-1}$ are invertibles.

Comment: You are right, we should read $A, B \in M(n, \mathbb{R})$.